# Using join with space in key

Tags: join, csv-simple

I'm having issues merging two files using the join command:
The first file is a csv file:

```
NAIN GENIEU 01/01/1900,A,B
NAIN GENIEUR 01/01/1917,C,D
NAINGENIEUR 21/01/1917,E,F
```

The second file contains only the interesting id:

```
NAIN GENIEUR 01/01/1917
```

I would like this as output:

```
NAIN GENIEUR 01/01/1917,C,D
```

Both files are sorted with bash `sort` command. When I use join without any argument it default to spaces so it joints by `PSEUDO` but doesn't account for `BIRTHDAY` or anything after a space in `PSEUDO`.
When I use `-t","`argument, I have no output at all (even though there should be)

Any clue on how to solve this? BTW I use join v.8.4

**EDIT** I tried putting quotation marks around the first field (which may contain spaces) but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please show us a more complete example and the output you expect to see. What you describe should work, if it doesn't, there's something going on with your data. Please [edit] your question and add a minimal example of the two files that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I edited my question, hope it makes it clearer

Comment: Sorry I meant csv file I didn't know they were different types.

Comment: @naingenieu There are multiple types all called CSV, but if you take advantage of the full range of things allowed, you cannot use line oriented tools like `sed` and `join` to work with them.

Comment: @Anthon, my bad, didn't know, I corrected my question :-) thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Your fields do not match (at least in the example)
The File that you are calling "full csv" has the field "PSEUDO BITHDAY" whereas the the second file has the field "PSEUDO BI**R**THDAY" 
There is an extra R in the second file.

The option -t works well in all releases of join.

**EDIT :**
Your example works for  me

```
    bash-4.1$ join -t, a b
    NAIN GENIEUR 01/01/1917,C,D
    bash-4.1$ join --version
    join (GNU coreutils) 8.4
    Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

    Written by Mike Haertel.
    bash-4.1$
```

Comment: My bad it was just a typo, i've remplaced it with examples.

Comment: You now seem to have leading blank spaces in tha master file on line 2 & 3 .. is that a typo too ?

Comment: No that seems to be a formatting issue one the website.

Comment: @naingenieu please see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting. Tiny differences are important, you need to make sure that what we see is exactly what you have in your files.

Answer (score 1):

Your command should work. However, at least in the example you show, you have a space at the end of the line in `file2`. That is important, it is taken as part of the field. As you can see, removing it joins the files as expected:

```
$ join -t"," -j 1 file1 file2  ## no output
$ sed -i 's/ $//' file2        ## remove the trailing space
$ join -t"," -j 1 file1 file2  ## now it works
NAIN GENIEUR 01/01/1917,C,D
```